# Combining netduino with Ethernet Shield

Tags: ethernet, netduino, microsd

While buying hardware, the Netduino Plus was not available so I bought Netduino and Ethernet shield. These days I have been trying to create and example of web server using Netduino and Ethernet shield and so far haven't got it working. I've tried to read and write to SD card mounted on shield but none of the examples I have found on the internet have worked.

Has anyone combined Netduino and Ethernet shield and successfully created any project which included SD card reading/writing and/or network communication?

If anyone knows what are the required libraries, how to set up a development environment (configuration in VS) and is perhaps willing to share a piece of code that works I would be really thankful!

Comment: Have you tried to figure out what about the example code isn't working? When you get to firmware things are rarely plug and play. The only way to get good at working with this stuff is to try to do some debugging on your own. If you are able to find a specific issue then we will be able to provide much better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the Netduino is working perfectly with Ethernet Shield. In order to get it working I had to do the following:

- solder 6-pin ICSP header on Netduino board
- connect D4 with D10 with jumper wire (this was neccesary for SD card
  reading/writing)
- upgrade firmware to 4.1.1 Beta 1

After successfully executing an example program for reading/writing SD card I wrote an [article](http://mypetprojects.blogspot.com/2011/10/netduino-using-ethernet-shield-to.html) and [uploaded VS2010 solution](http://www.2shared.com/file/mma_0y5m/HelloNetduinoSD.html) in case anyone meets the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

I got my my Netduino plus recently but have not had a chance to work with it yet. I did also buy a book about it: "Getting started with the internet of things" by Cuno Pfister, an O'Reilly publication.

I can tell you what the book says are the requirements:

1) Microsoft Visual studio 2010 or newer. The free Visual studio express is sufficient. However you need to install the C# [edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads).

2) [Microsoft.NET Micro Framework 4.1 SDK](http://www.netduino.com/downloads/MicroFrameworkSDK.msi) or newer

3) Your developement boards [SDK and drivers](http://www.netduino.com/downloads/).

All of these are free. It would be interesting to hear of your progress. Good luck!